# How do I take out a specific part of a string and save the remaning string in a variable?

Tags: php, string

I want to look for a sub-string within a string and if it is found I want to take out the sub-string that was found. ex
I'm looking for the word hello in the string helloworld.
if the sub-string is found I want to take out that sub-string and save the rest that was left over in a variable.
`$newVar = 'world';`
I have a code that looks for a sub-string in a string:

```
$originalStr = 'helloworld'
$strToCompare = 'hello';
if (stristr($originalStr, $strToCompare)){
  //take out the string that was found and save the rest in a variable.
    $newVar = 'world';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `strpos` function which is used to find the occurrence of one string inside other:

```
$originalStr = 'helloworld';
$strToCompare = 'hello';

if (strpos($originalStr, $strToCompare)!== FALSE) {
    $newVar = str_replace($strToCompare,'',$originalStr);
}
```

**Note** that you need to compare with the `!==` operator **NOT** `!=`.